# Will the auto/global variables inside a particular thread visible to other thread

Tags: c, multithreading, operating-system

I have been asked in an interview, Will the  auto/global variables inside a particular thread visible to other thread?Since Threads uses same address space it looks like its visible 
but i guess each thread has its own control block it should not be visible.

What's your take on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Edit: oops, I've answered for C++ instead of C. But C11 is somewhat similar to C++11: it also has "thread storage duration" and it also uses "visible" in both senses I describe below. So the answer is pretty much the same for both. Prior to the C(++)11 standards, Posix and other threading models had globals with thread-local storage for years.]

Define "visible"[*].

The memory is "visible", in the sense that if you have an address of the object then you can access it from another thread. Possibly with undefined behavior, if you create a data race.

Globals with static storage duration are also "visible" in the sense that the name of the global refers to the same object in all threads.

Globals with thread storage duration have a separate object per thread, and the name refers to the object belonging to the thread in which the code is executing. So they aren't "visible" to different threads by name, but the object itself is still accessible if you decide to pass the address from one thread to another.

Automatic variables aren't even "visible" by name in the *same* thread, from any scope other than the one they're defined in. The name of an automatic variable refers to the object created for the current invocation of the function. If the function is recursive, there can be more than one such invocation per thread, each with its own set of automatic variables of the same names. If the function is called concurrently from different threads then likewise each has its own automatic variables. So the names aren't "visible" from different threads. Again, the objects themselves are accessible.

[*] In the C++11 standard, 1.10 uses the word "visible" in the sense of the memory being visible, not in the sense of a name referring to a single object in different threads/scopes. But it doesn't formally define the word. It also uses "visible" in the sense of a name being in scope in 3.3.2/2, and elsewhere uses "visible" in at least two other contexts that I've found so far.

Comment: *6.2.4, p6: The
result of attempting to indirectly access an object with automatic storage duration from a
thread other than the one with which the object is associated is implementation-defined.*

Answer (score 0):

If the threads in question belong to the same process, (or the processor/OS does not provide protected process memory management), then yes.

Comment: but each thread having its own stack and auto variable go store on stack ,so if we see this way answer would be NO.

Comment: Each thread has its own stack and registers, but all threads' stacks are visible in the shared address space.

If one thread allocates some object on its stack, and sends the address to another thread, they'll both have equal access to that object.